# SQL: Viewing the latest ID based on latest updated timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

If i have the below data:

```
    route_name     updatedDate          route_id
    FF          15/06/2012 0:00         22
    DD          15/06/2012 0:00         31
    FF          16/06/2012 0:00         23
    FF          17/06/2012 0:00         24
    DD          17/06/2012 0:00         32
    DD          17/06/2012 18:00            
    FF          18/06/2012 0:00         
    FF          18/06/2012 19:00        40
    DD          20/06/2012 0:00         60
```

I want to run a query where i only see the `route_id` based in the latest `updatedDate` for the given route_name, so for example for route_name `FF` above the `route_id` should be 40.

I tried to do this using:

```
    select route_name,route_id,max(updatedDate) from route_de 
    group by route_name,route_id,updatedDate
    having count(*) >= 1
    order by route_name
```

but i get many repeated rows because of the updatedDate field (this is a big table). Can someone please suggest a way to archive the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select route_de.route_name, route_de.route_id from route_de join
(select max(updatedDate) as maxDate, route_name from route_de group by route_name) maxRoutes
on maxRoutes.maxDate = route_de.updatedDate and maxRoutes.route_name = route_de.route_name
```